# Having issues starting MySQL Daemon

Tags: mysql, database, daemon, dedicated-server

I'm new to the forums here but I hope to become more active as I've recently purchased a dedicated server and I'm running Fedora off of it so it's a constant learning process, I'm fairly average at BASH, but I know enough to make my way around, I'm a software developer to trade more than a network techi. Which leads me to my initial problem, I'm having an issue starting my MySQL daemon after rebooting my dedi, I have no clue why it's suddenly doing this, I'm running PHPMyAdmin from the server and also issuing certain commands through the CLI for MySQL, but after rebooting I'm getting this error everytime I try to start the instance of the daemon:

```
[root@ks23085 ~]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start mysqld.service
[root@ks23085 ~]# systemctl mysqld start
Unknown operation mysqld
[root@ks23085 ~]# systemctl start mysqld
Failed to issue method call: Unit name mysqld is not valid.
[root@ks23085 ~]# systemctl start mysqld.service
[root@ks23085 ~]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/path/to/mysql.sock' (2)
```

It's completely bizarre as it was working perfectly before I rebooted it, I didn't update it or change the install, the only thing that I did do was install postfix, but I don't see why that would cause any issues with MySQL :S

I really need a hand on this one, I've tried several solutions from google with no results whatsoever. Thanks in advance guys.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Update 1:

Okay, so I found the directory that mysqld is held, it was '/usr/libexec/mysqld', I typed './mysqld start' in this directory and it specifies this output:

```
120729  1:49:09 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
120729  1:49:09 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
120729  1:49:09 [Warning] Can't create test file /run/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
120729  1:49:09 [Warning] Can't create test file /run/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
./mysqld: Can't change dir to '/run/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
120729  1:49:09 [ERROR] Aborting

120729  1:49:09 [Note] ./mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Update 2:

I managed to get passed the directory issue by creating the 'mysql' directory in 'run/' with all my old databases, but now I seem to be getting an error that doesn't seem to be as easy to fix :/

Here's the output:

```
120729  2:15:59 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
120729  2:15:59 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
120729  2:15:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /run/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
120729  2:15:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /run/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
120729  2:15:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120729  2:15:59 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120729  2:15:59 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120729  2:15:59 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
120729  2:15:59 [ERROR] Aborting

120729  2:15:59 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Mysqld its probably failing to start up. go to the mysql install folder and run the mysqld daemon from there (not as a service) so it prints you the log, paste it here.

Comment: Where is the mysql install folder on fedora? Because I can't seem to find the mydql daemon in /etc/mysql/ any ideas?

Comment: execute rpm -ql mysqld. This will give you the list for the package myslqd. If you package is called myslq-server-<version number> or whatever - use that name. That is only if you installed the package via the package manager.

Comment: That command just tells me that mysqld is not installed, I have installed mysql-server using yum though :S

Comment: That seems like a permission problem - try to create the directory /run/mysql (if it does not exist) and change the ownership recursively to the mysql user.

Comment: @hovanessyan Yeh, I just done that, added an update with the new issue as your solution solved the last :) But I have anothe problem now, it's in update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official doc](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,27769,59865) states that there's 2 possible reasons for this error:

> 1. You don't have permissions to access the directory /var/lib/mysql/whatever.sock because mysql is the owner of the folder
>      or
> 2. /path/whatever.sock doesn't exist.

Execute the following to find your socket:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

Added to configuration file as suggested:

> You can try this though [Linux specific, but what other operating
>   systems are there?] Go to /etc/my.cnf and change/add the lines:
>
> [mysqld]
>
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>
> socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
>
> [client]
>
> socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

2) Don't forget to check your permissions!

Comment: I'm logged in as root, so I definitely have permissions, I've configured my.cnf already, it just seems to ignore the fact that I've updated it.

This is what I get when I execute '':
`code
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/path/to/mysql.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/path/to/mysql.sock' exists!
`

Comment: you need to reload or restart the service in order for the new configuration to kick in.

Comment: How do I do this? Because there isn't an instance of mysqld running :S

Comment: can you include the contents of your /etc/hosts file? Make sure you have there: "127.0.0.1 localhost"

Comment: also check if you find mysqld in /etc/init.d/

Comment: Yeh,"127.0.0.1 localhost" is in the hosts file, but mysqld isn't in init.d for some reason :S

Comment: did you installed it on the machine or it was there from the start? if you installed it - how did you do it? with what commands and as who (I mean as a user in the system)?

Comment: I installed it using yum install mysql mysql-server, as the root user

Comment: you can also try "yum install yum-utils" and than execute "repoquery --list mysql-server" this way you will find where the executables are.

Comment: Okay, I found it in '/var/run/mysqld' I ran './mysqld start' but it says I don't have permission to use the file despite being the root user :S

Comment: Update: I chmod'd the file and found the actual my.cnf file and changed the mysql.sock to an actual directory. Does mysqld create the sock? What else do I need to do?

Comment: /var/run does not sound like the right location. Have you used the commands I wrote? why don't you update your question with the output, for the list of the files of the mysql-server package?

Comment: I found the right directory for it, it's '/usr/libexec/mysqld', I tried running it. I'll specify the output in an update in the original question.